# how to conditionally replace values in list of lists in python

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I am a python new bie.
I have two list of lists like this:

```
A = List[List[float,float]]   
B = List[List[float,float]]
```

both different sizes
Ex :

```
A has [time, value]  
B has [start_time, end_time]  


A = [[0.0,10.0] , [1.0,10.0], [2.0,10.0], [3.0,10.0], [4.0,10.0],  [5.0,10.0],  [6.0,10.0]]
B = [[0.0,2.0], [5.0,6.0]]
```

What I am trying to do is :
 if A has a time which is not in B, I should make the corresponding 'value' in A to zero.

So output would be :

```
[[0.0,10.0] , [1.0,10.0], [2.0,10.0], [3.0,0.0], [4.0,0.0],  [5.0,10.0],  [6.0,10.0]]
```

i.e if a time segment in B has no corresponding time value present in A, the value corresponding to that time should be made zero. In this case, the values between 2 and 5 are there in B , so  partner values of'3' and '4' in A are made to zeroes.

Please tell me how to do it.
I have referred here: [Python - How to change values in a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752461/python-how-to-change-values-in-a-list-of-lists)  and [List of lists into numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346336/list-of-lists-into-numpy-array)

So One idea i got was to convert B into single list and then compare values from AA and A. However I haven't made much progress.

```
AA = numpy.hstack(B) # for getting array of times
for i in 1: len(AA):
     if (AA[i]==A[
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simple problems, a nested loop design can often get you to a quick solution without needing to worry about the specifics of list-flattening functions.

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    time = A[i][0]
    isValidTime = False
    for time_segment in B:
        if time_segment[0] <= time <= time_segment[1]:
            isValidTime = True
            break
    if not isValidTime:
        A[i][1] = 0.0
```

Edit: Just to be clear, including the 'break' statement isn't necessary to get to the solution, but it helps avoid unnecessary computation. If we've determined that an item in A does have a valid time, we can safely stop searching through the time segments in B and move on to the next item of A.

Answer (score 2):

If you [flatten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) B, then you can compare it:

```
A = [[0.0, 10.0], [1.0, 10.0], [2.0, 10.0], [3.0, 10.0], [4.0, 10.0], [5.0, 10.0], [6.0, 10.0]]
B = [[0.0, 2.0], [5.0, 6.0]]

Bvals = [item for sublist in B for item in sublist]
print(Bvals)
newA = [x if x[0] in Bvals else [x[0], 0.0] for x in A]
print(newA)

Outputs:
[0.0, 2.0, 5.0, 6.0]
[[0.0, 10.0], [1.0, 0.0], [2.0, 10.0], [3.0, 0.0], [4.0, 0.0], [5.0, 10.0], [6.0, 10.0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the `B` list contains time intervals, right? In that case, you can do something like the following:

```
updated = [x if any([start <= x[0] end <= for start, end in B]) else [x[0], 0] for x in A]
```

That may be a bit too compact for some people, but it essentially does the same as the following:

```
updated = []
for time, value in A:
    for start, end in B:
        if start <= time and time <= end:
            updated.append([time, value])
            break
    updated.append([time, 0])
```

On a side note, if you are doing interval checking, this is probably not the most efficient way to do it. Take a look at [interval trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree), which is a data structure for performing various interval-related queries (yours included).

Answer (score 2):

#### A `Pythonic` one-liner:

```
[[t,v if any(s <= t and t <= e for s,e in B) else 0.0] for t,v in A]
```

which gives:

```
[[0.0, 10.0], [1.0, 10.0], [2.0, 10.0], [3.0, 0.0], [4.0, 0.0], [5.0, 10.0], [6.0, 10.0]]
```